# How can I disable Excel 2013 on Windows 8 from asking for login credentials on some Web Query calls?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

We've built a web query view in our application, returning some reports as a simple formatted table (with PRE tags etc. as required). Our app requires a login naturally, but its basically an API layer, but with the right access token you don't need to log in. The report returns just fine if you hit it in a browser with the access token (status code 200, output is as expected etc.). The url looks like

`http://www.example.com/api/1/reports/1/?token=1234567890`

However, when we try to hit the URL from Excel 2013 Web Query, we first get the data in the preview window just fine, we select the table and import. At that point we're asked to enter our credentials in a login window. Nothing we enter there helps and after 3 attempts we get an "Unkonwn Error" alert. I've seen a few places on the net suggesting to set up some registry keys etc, but nothing works.
The same query works in Excel 2003. Also, other "sites" we try also seem to work without the login prompt.
Any idea what is going on?

[image: The login form from hell]

Comment: Where are you getting the query from? Within your network? Sharepoint? External data? Also, how is the query setup? With the wizard? VBA? Power query? What kind of database are you connecting to?

Comment: You website must be returning a different answer than the other websites that don't ask for a logon. Use the [Fiddler web debugger](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to trace both requests : 1. to your website, 2. to another one, then post both here. Be careful to include all message headers in the return message when posting.

Comment: I will get the details, though before that, I must say that the preview window show the data table just fine - only when i click Import the login window shows up. As well, the request returns a proper 200 status code (as opposed to a 401 etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as an answer though I'm not entirely sure it qualifies as one, as the situation deteriorated from strange to straight up weird:

Turns out the preview of the request, coming from that IE component panel worked ok sending the full url (yes, https) with the query parameters including the token which grants the access. However, when excel was sending the request it was sending it without any query parameters thus having it rejected. I moved the token for this request to be part of the url like so:

`https://www.example.com/report/5/_token-1234asdfg5678zxcv/`

But Excel refused to send the url with anything past the /5/ (a report id in my case). I cannot explain that part. But it gets stranger. 
If I move the token before the report id, it works!

`https://www.example.com/report/_token-1234asdfg5678zxcv/5/`

Not over yet, because Excel refuses to send the trailing slash. So the final url was:

`https://www.example.com/report/_token-1234asdfg5678zxcv/5`

I don't see it as a solution as I don't understand why excel was doing that, but then again, Excel is black magic to me.

Not sure what to do with the bounty. @harrymc, your comment directed me to start monitoring the server logs (didn't thinking of it before for some reason)

Comment: +1 as it solves the problem. I posted my comment as an answer, even though it's only the start of one. There is no point in trying to figure why Excel behaves this way - it's probably a bug or more than one. Inscrutable are the ways of MS.

Answer (score 0):

Is the site https? According to this you cannot auth through http.  [hyperlink cannot be followed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e2aef460-5500-4a76-8b36-c3d93208267e/excel-2013-webquery-hyperlink-cannot-be-followed-to-the-destination?forum=excel)

Answer (score 0):

Though your URL is http and not https, you may want to look for these headers:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

If those headers are not there, Excel does all the authentication stuff a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You website must be returning a different answer than the other websites that don't ask for a logon.

You could use the [Fiddler web debugger](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to trace both requests :

1. to your website,
2. to a website that works

The difference between the two might point out the reason why one works and the
other doesn't.

Post both traces here if you wish us to have a look at them,
including especially all message headers in the return messages.

Comment: This comment-now-answer is what helped me find the solution. Enjoy your bounty, don't spend it all at once :)